# Local server works, online server fails - Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, passport.js

I have a node app set up. When using a local set up of Mongo things post to the database just fine. When I switch the database to MLab it breaks the app. I'm getting zero error messages other than it's timing out. Any thoughts? Here's my app set up and the register route thats failing. Seems odd that it would work perfectly on my local host but not the cloud?

```
// mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/cultureapp3");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://INFO.mlab.com:/INFO");


app.set("view-engine", "ejs");
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(flash());




// //PASSPORT CONFIG
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Hawaii.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
   res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
   res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
   next();
});
```

Here's the register route.

```
//handle register 
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){ 
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            console.log(err.message)
            return res.redirect("/register");
        } 

        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
             req.flash("success", "Successfully logged in as " + user.username);
            res.redirect("/progress")
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: use `docker`, and you'll never have to ask a question like this.

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for the tip. Can you tell me a little about docker?

Comment: https://www.docker.com/what-docker - basically you have exactly the same environment on local and on any server you deploy

Comment: Looks awesome. Definitely will check it out. Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out after contacting mLab! Such a small but devastating error:

I was trying to connect with the "<>" characters around my username/password in the connection URI.

Removed those and it works like a charm.